# clj-webdriver in clojure: where to find taxi.clj?

Tags: clojure, webdriver

There is a namespace of clj-webdriver.taxi in clj-webdriver. But where to find out the clojure file, I can't find it in github of https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The taxi api is being removed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/clj-webdriver/taxi/clj-webdriver/0dbxejlPi38/jRAPOuIeAwAJ). Tag [0.7.2](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/tree/v0.7.2) still has the file.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find it in github, but in the jar file I could find the taxi.clj